# I am trying to create a slide animation with css3 animations, why its overriding each other while silidng..?

Tags: css

I am trying to create slide animation with css3 animations but it's not working properly it's overriding each other while sliding, can you please please explain me what i did mistake below is my code....

[This is my codepen](http://codepen.io/venumadhavdiv/pen/vGLXKP?editors=0100)

```
    .slide{
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
    /*SLIDE1*/
    .one{
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        animation-name: example1;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-delay: 1.5s;
        x-animation-timing-function: ease;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @keyframes example1 {
        0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
        100% {left:1024px; top:0px;}
    }
    /*SLIDE2*/
    .two{
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: green;
        position: absolute;
        animation-name: example2;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-delay: 3s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        x-animation-timing-function: ease;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes example2 {
        0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
        100% {left:1024px; top:0px;}
    }
    .three{
      width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: blue;
        position: absolute;
        animation-name: example3;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-delay: 4.5s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        x-animation-timing-function: ease;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    @keyframes example3 {
        0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
        100% {left:1024px; top:0px;}
    }
```

Comment: it's do what you wright. explain, what you expect to do you code?

Comment: I need css slider, that should go one after another like javascript and jquery slider...it's sliding but its overriding on each other you can see that in my codepen....

Answer (score 0):

if you want a sliding with only css cand try bellow code

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shayanypn/LuzpsaL6/)

```
#slider-wrapper {
  width: 940px;
  height: 470px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#s1 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: -36px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s2 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s3 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s4 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 36px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s1:hover,
#s2:hover,
#s3:hover,
#s4:hover {
  opacity: .50;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  width: 940px;
  height: 470px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.control {
  display: none;
}

#Slide1:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

#Slide2:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#Slide3:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#Slide4:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#Slide1:checked + #s1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Slide2:checked + #s2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Slide3:checked + #s3 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Slide4:checked + #s4 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.overflow-wrapper {
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```

and html

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <input checked type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide1" />
    <label for="Slide1" id="s1"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide2" />
    <label for="Slide2" id="s2"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide3" />
    <label for="Slide3" id="s3"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide4" />
    <label for="Slide4" id="s4"></label>
    <div class="overflow-wrapper">
      <a class="slide" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/940x470" /></a>
      <a class="slide" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/940x470" /></a>
      <a class="slide" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/940x470" /></a>
      <a class="slide" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/940x470" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the modify of your code
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shayanypn/LuzpsaL6/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer shayanypn..but it's won't work with my code??
it's just casual slider.

Comment: @VenuMadhav i add your modify codes.i hope it's what you want